# How to store City, State and Country data related json in single area

Tags: javascript, json

I like to know how to construct or store json data for City, State and Country in a single variable ?

I have seen one but it only deal with single kind of data means **CAR**

```
{
    "cars": {
        "Nissan": [
            {"model":"Sentra", "doors":4},
            {"model":"Maxima", "doors":4}
        ],
        "Ford": [
            {"model":"Taurus", "doors":4},
            {"model":"Escort", "doors":4}
        ]
    }
}
```

My intention is to store different kind of json data in single area or in single variable.

Comment: What do you mean by "in single variable"?

Comment: i like to store the json of different object in single variable.

Comment: Which programmar language do you want to use? Storing data in json format is available in many programmar language (see json.org). So please add a relevant tag to your post.

Comment: could you explain a little further on how you are going to be using that data in your program?

Comment: i am working with javascript. so i need to see the structure of json having data with different object like say customer info, order info in same place.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this ?

```
{
  "countries": [
    {...}
  ],

  "states" [
    {...}
  ],

  "cities": [
    {...}
  ]

}
```

Comment: You are missing the attributes for state and city.

Comment: i asked how to store data about country, state and city in same place. u just have country related json shown.....tell me how could i have state and city related json store there. am i clear ?

Comment: Check the answer, if I properly understand what you're asking.

Comment: it is ok but u just give empty json. it would be great if u fill the json with data for for multiple countries, few states and few cities. thanks

Comment: Can't you do that yourself..?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is a direct answer.

```
{
"Countries":[{
        "CountryName":"Indonesia",
        "States":[{
                    "StateName":"Bali",
                            "Cities":["Denpasar",
                            "Kuta",
                            "Tuban"
                              ]},
                     {
                     "StateName":"Jakarta",
                     "Cities":[
                                "Bandung",
                                "Tanggerang"
                              ]
                      }
                   ]
         }]}
```

check the file here
[jsonforcountriesstatecities](https://github.com/sagarshirbhate/Country-State-City-Database)